# Group By dengan Count & Order By in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

please help
`SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(USER_ID) FROM ticket_table GROUP BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY COUNT(USER_ID) DESC LIMIT 10;`
for the following query when implemented in the Laravel query builder, what kind of controller is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this :

```
\DB::table('ticket_table')
->selectRaw('customer, count(user_id)')
->groupBy('customer')
->orderBy(\DB::raw('COUNT(user_id)'), 'DESC')
->limit(10);
```